# Estou fazendo uma calculadora usando tkinter integrado no python

Tags: python, tkinter

estou com uma dificuldade de atribuir ao botao AC(claear) a funçao limpar tela, coloquei um
def clear():
frame.destroy()
isso realmente limpa a tela porém, nao consigo usar a tela para escrever, aqui está meu codigo

```
from tkinter import*
```

from tkinter import ttk

#tela
calculadora = Tk()
calculadora.geometry("400x500")
calculadora.title("Calculadora")
calculadora.grid()
frame = Frame(calculadora)
frame.pack(side= TOP)
frame.pack()
#variaveis

#def
def butt0():
Label(frame, text='0', font=('arial', 10)).pack()
def claear():
frame.destroy()
#front
btn0 = Button(calculadora, text="0",height=5, width=12, command=butt0)
btn1 = Button(calculadora, text="1",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn2 = Button(calculadora, text="2",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn3 = Button(calculadora, text="3",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn4 = Button(calculadora, text="4",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn5 = Button(calculadora, text="5",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn6 = Button(calculadora, text="6",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn7 = Button(calculadora, text="7",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn8 = Button(calculadora, text="8",height=5, width=12, command="")
btn9 = Button(calculadora, text="9",height=5, width=12, command="")
btnM1 = Button(calculadora, text="+",height=5, width=10, command="")
btnM2 = Button(calculadora, text="-",height=5, width=10, command="")
btnV = Button(calculadora, text="x",height=5, width=10, command="")
btnD = Button(calculadora, text="/",height=5, width=10, command="")
btnI = Button(calculadora, text="=",height=5, width=12, command="")
btnAC = Button(calculadora, text="AC",height=5, width=12, command=claear)

btnAC.place(x=2, y=413)
btn0.place(x=107, y=413)
btnI.place(x=209, y=413)
btnD.place(x=313, y=413)
btn1.place(x=2, y=325)
btn2.place(x=107, y=325)
btn3.place(x=209, y=325)
btnM1.place(x=313, y=325)
btn4.place(x=2, y=233)
btn5.place(x=107, y=233)
btn6.place(x=209, y=233)
btnM2.place(x=313, y=233)
btn7.place(x=2, y=141)
btn8.place(x=107, y=141)
btn9.place(x=209, y=141)
btnV.place(x=313, y=141)

calculadora = mainloop()

Answer (score -2):

Tens que definir a variável da label fora da função e depois para cada botão adicionas o número. Para limpar a label colocas uma string vazia.

```
label = Label(frame, text='', font=('arial', 10))
label.pack()

def butt0(): 
    label['text'] += "0"
def claear(): 
    label['text'] = ""
```